RabbitMQ on Windows with SSL for message queues
We have just set up RabbitMQ on a Windows server and want to use SSL for it.  I've read through the documentation but this only goes through using an untrusted "testca" cert.  I wish to use either:
A cert generated from our internal CA or a publicly generated cert from Let's Encrypt.
Setting up the GUI to use SSL has been done via the .Conf file, as has the listener confing, but I am struggling to get the message queues to use SSL, so is now accessible via https://rabbitmqserver.domain.com:15671.  Looking at the RabbitMQ logs shows that the listener is listening on port 5671.
The logs are also stating:

2024-08-20 10:52:17.017000+01:00 [notice] <0.10369.0> TLS server: In state wait_finished >received CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Certificate Unknown


2024-08-20 10:52:58.217000+01:00 [error] <0.10389.0> ** Connection attempt from node >'rabbitmqcli-410-rabbit@server' rejected. Invalid challenge reply. **

Has anyone used either of the above methods successfully and can point me in the right direction, please?
Thanks.
